# apache camel tracer not working with logging Out Exchanges

Tags: apache-camel

I am using Tracer for logging in and out messages. When i enabled logging out messages, it is logging successfully but in my Rest Client I am not getting the response.Can anybody help me to fix this.

Comment: See this FAQ when you have an empty body problem: http://camel.apache.org/why-is-my-message-body-empty.html

Comment: I am using streamCache = true, still i have Problem only with Out Exchange.

Comment: There is a side effect when using the getOut() method from the exchange, it just create a new Out message if the out message is empty.  How did you logg out message?

Comment: ...and show us your route please...

Comment: I am using camel teacer property logOutExchange=true which will log out message..in console it is writting the out message as well